# counting the number of times a word is typed in

Tags: java, string, input, count, words

i found a solution similar to my problem here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Counter
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        String a = "", b = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Enter a string: " );
        a = s.nextLine();
        while ( b.length() != 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter a single character: " );
            b = s.next();
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ )
        {
            if ( b.equals(a.charAt( i ) +"") )
                counter++;
        }
        System.out.println( "Number of occurrences: " + counter );
    }
}
```

this program only counts the amount of times a selected letter appears. i need to do the same but with an entire word. How would i modify this code to do what I need it to? I'm not the greatest at programming. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [split string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

You can split the string on space like

```
String[] words =a.split(" ");
```

Then loop through it like

```
for(String word : words) {
    if(word.equals(testWordToCompare)
        counter++;
    }
}
```

So your new code would look like :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Counter
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        String a = "", testWordToCompare = "exist";
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Enter a string: " );
        a = s.nextLine();
        String[] words =a.split(" ");
        int counter = 0;
        for(String word : words) {
           if(word.equals(testWordToCompare)
               counter++;
           }
        }
        System.out.println( "Number of occurrences of " + testWordToCompare +" is : " + counter );
    }
}
```