# Program to count the number of times a word is entered then return the word and number of times used in descending order

Tags: java

The purpose is the create a program that will count the number of times a word is entered, while ignoring case and punctuation, then return the word along with the number of times it was entered to the console in descending order. Currently, my program counts the number of letters and returns it to the console, but it does not ignore case or punctuation. I also am not sure how to add the sort function. Thank you for your time / help.

Edit: Not sure what changed from original code, but when I ran it in eclipse this last time the punctuation and case were ignored by the counter. However, counter is still tracking letters instead of words.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String txt = readText();
    String[] words = txtToWords(normalize(txt));

    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = countWords(words);

    //Print to console how many times each word was entered 
    System.out.println(txt + "was found" + wordCount + "times");

}
    //Increases word counter by 1 each time a duplicate word is entered
public static HashMap<String, Integer> countWords(String[] words) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (wordCount.containsKey(word)) {
            int count = wordCount.get(word);
            count = count + 1;
            wordCount.put(word, count);
        } else {
            wordCount.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}

public static String[] txtToWords(String txt) {
    return txt.split("");
}
    //Removes punctuation and ignores case when counting
public static String normalize(String txt) {
    txt = txt.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
    return txt;
}
    //Reads the text entered by the user
public static String readText() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the text to be processed.");
    String stop = "*** LAST LINE ***";
    System.out.println("Enter: \"" + stop + "\" to stop");

    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(stop)) {
            break;
        } else {
            results.append(line);
        }
    }
    return results.toString().trim();
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: a Map can be viewed as a collection of entries. Map has a method to return this collection of entries. The entries can be stored in a List. And a List can be sorted using Collections.sort(). Read the javadoc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting the number of times a word is typed in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939674/counting-the-number-of-times-a-word-is-typed-in)

Comment: I have a general idea of how to sort, but before I get to that I would like to make sure the print to console is ignoring punctuation and case as well as counting words instead of letters. Can you point me in the right direction for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have left spaces in your string with the normalize method. You should split on these rather than an empty string:

```
str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: I tweaked the code a bit and the counter is now ignoring case and punctuation, but it's still counting letters instead of numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated. All I did was correct the line " txt = txt.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();" and the counter is now ignoring punctuation and case. It's still counting letters instead of words though.

Comment: What did you change on the replaceAll line? I think I missed it. Did you also change the str.split line? This should split on the white space between words rather than between letters.

Comment: I believe there was just an extra white space character that was causing an issue in the replaceAll line. I missed your initial comment to change the split line, that did the trick. It's now counting words. Thank you so much. I'm going to attempt to sort and will comment back if I have further issues. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, that's why I didn't notice the change :) Glad I could help. Would you mind marking the answer as accepted if it solved for you?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll create another question for the sorting if I need it. Thanks again.